# Pan flute physics

Tags: acoustics

We are trying to create a custom pan flute. With some searching, we found a formula relating the length of a closed cylinder with the frequency at which it resonates, namely L = c / 4f, with c being the speed of sound. Based on this, we calculated that a cylinder to produce 880 Hz, or A5, would need to be about 97.4 mm long. But, having printed such a cylinder with a 3D printer, when blown, it produces a frequency of about 840 Hz. We have checked and re-checked the dimensions, and the plastic does not appear to be porous at all. Why are we getting a different frequency than predicted by the theory?

Comment: More accurate formulas taking the *diameter* into account are in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_resonance#Resonance_of_a_tube_of_air).

Comment: [Here](https://www.atos.org/sites/default/files/pdf/programs-awards/EndCorrection_Complete_1.pdf)'s a nice read from the website of American Theatre Organ Society. While it deals with pipe organs, the physics essentially remains the same.

Answer (score 13):

Your formula ignored the "end correction" to the length of the pipe. The standing wave in the air does not end exactly at the end of the pipe, but at a distance approximately 0.6D outside it, where D is the pipe diameter.

If your pipe diameter was about 7mm, that would explain the difference between 880Hz and 840Hz.

Note that the "exact" length correction will also depend on the change to the air flow pattern around the pipe caused by your face, when you are blowing the instrument, so you will always have to make some minor adjustments by trial and error.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_correction.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** I feel that some of the comments might have missed the point of this answer: I'm not necessarily claiming that the *reason* for the error is because of the speed of sound, but rather that a 5% error is not unreasonable without more information on the experimental setup.

Nevertheless, I feel that my answer is not *incorrect* (though I'll admit that my original estimate of $\Delta c \approx 20$m/s might have been a little overzealous), so I have changed it to (I feel) a more reasonable $5$m/s.

---

Well, I'm not expert at this, but it sounds like a pretty decent result, given the conditions! It's an error of under 5%, which -- at least in the undergraduate labs I've worked in -- is pretty acceptable.

The key is to ask yourself how certain you are of the final frequency, and I'm not even talking about the theoretical result, which itself might need to be adjusted depending on the level of accuracy you require. Assuming your formula holds: $$f = \frac{c}{4 L},$$

these quantities are not defined to infinite precision, and they have their own uncertainties which propagate into the frequency. A standard result from error analysis shows that the relative uncertainty you can expect in the frequency is more or less: $$\frac{\Delta f}{f} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\Delta c}{c}\right)^2  + \left(\frac{\Delta L}{L}\right)^2}$$

Now, $c$ the speed of sound is not necessarily a constant (it changes with the temperature and pressure, for example). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) deals with this in some detail, and it seems like the speed could vary from around 340 m/s (at 15$^\circ$C) to around 350 m/s (at 30$^\circ$C), and this isn't taking into account the effect of pressure. So let's take $\Delta c \approx 5$m/s. Similarly, the measurement of your length will have some uncertainty, which I assume will be of the order of a millimetre or so (I could be wrong, I have very little experience with the precision of 3D printers). In this case,

$$\frac{\Delta f}{f} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{5}{340}\right)^2  + \left(\frac{1}{97.4}\right)^2} \approx 0.02.$$

In other words, using these uncertainties, you'd get a relative error of roughly 6%, which seems to line up quite nicely with the value that you have. So when you say that you calculated that such a cylinder should produce 880 Hz, it would be more appropriate to say that your calculation would give a frequency of 880 $\pm$ 20 Hz, and your answer does fall quite close to that range, depending on how certain you are of your estimate of "about" 840 Hz.

Since the majority of the error comes from the uncertainty in $c$, it should be possible to do better if you have a better estimate for it, but I do remember it being notoriously difficult to settle on.

---

**EDIT:**
All of this being said, I have indicated above that the theoretical formula the OP used may be inadequate, and it looks like alephzero's answer *could* be correct, but without more details about your apparatus, I can't be sure.

However, taking it at face value, if the formula is indeed: $$f = \frac{c}{4(L + 0.6 D)},$$ then in order to obtain a frequency of 840 Hz given a length of 97.4 mm, one would require $D \approx 8$mm, which might well be the case. **Nevertheless:** this just means that we have one more term to add to our error analysis! Now, again, I am not sure of the precision to which you know $D$, but if it's up to 1mm, then you can show that

$$\frac{\Delta f}{f} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\Delta c}{c}\right)^2 + \frac{(\Delta L)^2 + (0.6 \Delta D)^2}{(L + 0.6 D)^2}} \approx 0.02,$$

which again seems to indicate that a 2% error is pretty much the best you can do.

Comment: Since you have only two variables, I would use a trial and error approach. Make the cylinder slightly to long, and take a file until you get the right frequency. Excellent answer by the way!

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea, I didn't think of that. Might be good to also know how the OP actually measures the frequency to know how reliable that is. A lot of this is an art, which is only to be expected! I feel it gives one new respect for those who make musical instruments :)

Comment: +1 Very clear and informative example of a simple manufacturing process.

Comment: Unfortunately, a difference of $\pm 50 \mathrm{Hz}$ is noticeable to the trained musical ear...

Comment: @wyphan My point exactly! :) Going by the formula can only take you so far. Which is why I really like Bernhard's suggestion, it would allow someone to carefully "tune" the instrument.

Comment: Assuming $\Delta c \approx 20$m/s is not very realistic, since it would need an air temperature of about 53C not 20C. The cause is more likely to be ignoring the "end correction" when calculating the theoretical length,

Comment: That's true, but even temperatures between 20$^\circ$ and 30$^\circ$ C could cause a $\Delta c \approx 10$m/s, and even such a difference would lead to an error of roughly 3%, which is also reasonable, given the data. But you're right, this is a very basic analysis, and the first step would be to add any theoretical corrections. Though wouldn't you agree that having a very accurate value for $c$ is a prerequisite to any further calculations?

Comment: -1.  This answer is incorrect.  The OP seems to have assumed $c=343$ m/s, which is the standard speed of sound in dry air at $20^\circ$ C.  Room temperature is typically higher than this, so the expected error due to the exact value of $c$ would lead to a *higher* frequency, not lower.  Non-zero humidity also increases sound speed, and thus frequency.  The only way this answer could provide a correct explanation is if the flute were being played at about $-8^\circ$ C, which is very implausible.  alephzero's answer is the correct explanation for the OP.

Comment: @wyphan or even to an untrained one: 880/840 is about 0.8 semitones, so unless you're completely tone deaf it will sound honkingly out of tune when played alongside a correctly tuned instrument.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, guys, I've made a couple of edits to reflect them. That being said, @Yly I think it might be a little too harsh to say that my answer is *incorrect*. I don't believe there's anything I've said here that's *wrong* (though I'll admit that -- without more information -- it is possible that my answer doesn't provide the correct *reason* for the observation. That being said, I don't think it deserves a downvote, since I've been quite clear to qualify all my assumptions.

Comment: I guess this is not "incorrect" in the sense that if you use an over-simplified formula which is a poor model of the real-world system, you can invent some way of getting a better answer by changing the input (but not necessarily in a realistic way). Wind instrument makers can and do calculate the dimensions of the instrument to 0.1mm or less, to produce frequencies accurate to better than 0.1%. It has been known how to do that for at least 150 years, but you can't do it using an oversimplified formula you learned in high school.

Comment: @alephzero You're completely right, and as I pointed out in my original answer, I agree completely. I may have misunderstood your comment, but I hope you understand that I am not justifying the original formula, nor am I "changing" the input to fit the answer; I'm merely saying that *if* it is used, with certain reasonable assumptions of uncertainties (not professional grade precision, etc.) that I would expect in (say) an undergraduate lab, an error of 5% is not unreasonable. And yes, I am absolutely certain that instrument makers use more complicated formulae than this one ;)

Comment: “Room temperature is typically higher than [20°C]” — that depends very much where you are (and what time of year)…